# Is Date.now() okay to use, will it reach a number that JS can't handle?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a possibility that Date.now() will start returning numbers in scientific notation?

It can possibly be a bug like Y2K. Is it safe to use it? Will it cross the biggest
number possible in JavaScript?

Comment: A number is never "in scientific notation"; it might get displayed to you like that, but it's just a `Number` internally.

Comment: ```let x = 1000000000000000000000 // 1e+21```
```x === x + 10000 // true```

^ this can lead to a problem if Date.now() reaches a very high number. Despite it being a number internally is unable to get difference between ```x``` and ```x + 10000```

Comment: Sure, at some point you'll start losing accuracy. But by definition, if `Date.now()` returns a number, that number can never exceed the threshold of the highest number in Javascript. Since you're not dealing with integers that you can manually overflow yourself, but instead with a high level language on a very abstracted runtime, this really is a problem the Javascript engine needs to deal with and not your userland code.

Answer (score 3):

The [biggest integer (Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) can handle is `2^53 - 1`.

Converting that to years:

```
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365)
// outputs 285616.41472415626
```

So the answer is YES, it's safe to use it.

Answer (score 2):

That's not going to be a concern of yours:

`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` to `Date`:

> Wed 12 Oct 287396
>
> Relative: In 287.396‬ years

On the other hand

> The actual range of times supported by ECMAScript Date objects is slightly smaller: exactly –100,000,000 days to 100,000,000 days measured relative to midnight at the beginning of 01 January, 1970 UTC.

---

However unrelated, there is the [year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) which might set you off, but as mentioned is not related to JS

> The Year 2038 problem (also called Y2038 or Y2k38 or Unix Y2K) relates to representing time in many digital systems as the number of seconds passed since 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970 and storing it as a signed 32-bit integer. Such implementations cannot encode times after 03:14:07 UTC on 19 January 2038. Similar to the Y2K problem, the Year 2038 problem is caused by insufficient capacity used to represent time.

Date is funny :)

Comment: Even if it exceeds that threshold, you'll still be able to express times with it; they just might not be accurate to the second anymore.

Comment: What value did you use for `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` and how'd you convert that to the year 2255…?

Comment: @deceze I used `9007199254740991` and the site https://www.epochconverter.com/, but I see I am wrong :) it assumes microseconds, because of the sheer size of the number. It should be milliseconds

Comment: Looks like the MAX_SAFE_INTEGER used is wrong. In my calculations it result in ~285K years

Comment: @EliasSoares you are right, i've already updated my answer :). Which again seems to be different from your answer.. mmm

Comment: I've double checked the value. Also, the y2038 bug should not affect JavaScript since it limitation is Integer limit is greater then 32 bits (53 actually)

Comment: But your calculation is lot too far, looks like missing the miliseconds conversion.

Comment: @EliasSoares definitely :D just a factor 1000. I just added the 2038 bug as some background information :) but good to mention it's unrelated to JS